# Pythagorean triplet bruteforce algorithm breaks at 969

Tags: c, algorithm, pythagorean

I have this code written in C to find all possible Pythagorean triplets within a certain number range. The original algorithm I wrote, just nested for loops and `if(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2) == pow(c, 2))`, worked just fine. However, my new, more optimized algorithm, which only loops through a and b, setting c to `sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2))` and checking if `ceil(c) == c`, immediately begins accepting all whole numbers the moment b hits 969.

Furthermore, when I ran the second algorithm with a smaller amount and checked the results, the amount of triplets output is exactly 0.969x the limit of b (the top loop).

This is an extremely weird and interesting phenomenon, and I am unsure what makes 969 such a special number.

My new algorithm:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int limit;

    printf("Max value to bruteforce: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);

    unsigned int triples[limit][3]; // `0.969 * limit` is exact
    unsigned int i = 0;

    printf("Bruteforcing...\n");

    for(unsigned int b = 1; b < limit; b++) {
        for(unsigned int a = 1; a <= b; a++) {
            double c = sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2));
            
            if(ceil(c) == c) {
                triples[i][0] = a;
                triples[i][1] = b;
                triples[i][2] = c;
                    
                i++;

                printf("found: %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, (int) c);
            }
        }
    }
    
    char out[i + 15];

    sprintf(out, "%d\n", limit);
    
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < i; i2++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            char ln[10];
            sprintf(ln, "%d ", triples[i2][j]);

            strcat(out, ln);
        }

        strcat(out, "\n");
    }

    FILE *f = fopen("cache.txt", "w");
    fprintf(f, "%s", out);
    fclose(f);

    printf("Saved to cache.txt\n");
  return 0;
}
```

My old algorithm (reproduced, may not be 100% accurate):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int limit;

    printf("Max value to bruteforce: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);

    unsigned int triples[limit][3]; // `0.969 * limit` is exact
    unsigned int i = 0;

    printf("Bruteforcing...\n");

    for(unsigned int b = 1; b < limit; b++) {
        for(unsigned int a = 1; a <= b; a++) {
            for(unsigned int c = 1; c < limit; c++) {
                if(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2) == pow(c, 2)) {
                    triples[i][0] = a;
                    triples[i][1] = b;
                    triples[i][2] = c;
                    
                    i++;

                    printf("found: %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, (int) c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    char out[i + 15];

    sprintf(out, "%d\n", limit);
    
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < i; i2++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            char ln[10];
            sprintf(ln, "%d ", triples[i2][j]);

            strcat(out, ln);
        }

        strcat(out, "\n");
    }

    FILE *f = fopen("cache.txt", "w");
    fprintf(f, "%s", out);
    fclose(f);

    printf("Saved to cache.txt\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `pow(a, 2)` etc. `pow` is for floating points and you'll get inaccurate results when your store the result in an integer. Use `a * a`. Also `scanf("%d", &limit);` is wrong since `limit` is an `unsigned int`. Use `scanf("%u", &limit);` instead.

Comment: should the `%u` rule apply to all of my things such as `printf` as well?

Comment: (Not yor actual question, but `i + 15` as buffer size for a buffer to which you write at least 7 characters for each of `i` items seems insufficient. Why not write to `cache.txt` as you go with `fprintf` and save yourself some ugly `strcat`s on the way?)

Comment: Also: You access the arrays out of bounds. Arrays are zero-based in C, not 1-based.

Comment: @TedLyngmo for whatever reason, the `scanf` change you told me to do makes the number greater than what was inputted. is this just a thing that happens with unsigned ints in c? (new to c, mainly have been using rust)

Comment: You should avoid floating point math completely for this.  Replace `pow(a, 2)` with `a*a`, and in place of `sqrt`, you can use a simple Newton's method integer square root.  You could even use a simple search to determine if it's a perfect square - first bound it by doubling each time, then use a binary search.  Just beware of overflow.

Comment: @ahumanbeing If it becomes greater, then you gave a negative value or `scanf` failed. Always check the return value from `scanf`. And yes, if you `printf` an `unsigned`, use `%u`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the array is not being indexed at 1. the a, b, and c start at 1 simply to circumvent `0, 0, 0`

Comment: But you dimension your array with `limit` and index with `i`. They are not related and you could find more triplets than the limit. (Theoretically. I don't think the triplets are that dense, but you should check `i` before storing a new triplet.)

Comment: You could also add `printf("%u %zu\n", i + 15, strlen(out) + strlen(ln) + 1); fflush(stdout);` before `strcat(out, ln);` to see what the new length of the string will be in comparison to what space you allocated. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/jxvGrhjGG)

Comment: If you do use a search approach to determine whether `a*a + b*b` is a perfect square, it may help to recognize that given 0 < `a` <= `b`, the square root will lie between `b` and `a+b`, exclusive.

Comment: @ahumanbeing When doing integer `x * x` you may also want to use `unsigned long long`s - otherwise `65536^2` (and above) will overflow for a 32 bit `unsigned int`. Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/xn9Yrx69T) using `ipow_x2` and `isqrt` for integer^2 and square roots.

Comment: Related, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples has several more efficient approaches than brute force. If you're doing Project Euler, it is worthwhile figuring out how to do this.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/5K1sbMsbo) using `unsigned long long` that outputs the triplets in increasing order of c, secondarily sorted in increasing order of b. It stops when c would exceed the limit specified on the command line or when c*c would exceed the range of `unsigned long long`. It uses a different algorithm than @Ted's to calculate the square root (Ted used binary search. I used Heron's/Newton's method, which converges in fewer steps than binary search but might be slower due to use of division operations.)

Comment: It is also worth considering the efficient `a = m*m - n*n`, `b = 2*m*n`, `c = m*m + n*n` generators, but it is difficult to get sorted output that way.

Comment: @IanAbbott Those are primitive.  Throw in `k` as well. The difficulty is overstated - just use a priority queue.

Comment: Here is an efficient way to list triples, in order, in Python. It is good enough for lots of Project Euler problems.  https://gist.github.com/btilly/86a6c99aeaba18f6a2242b740196d7fb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am unsure what makes 969 such a special number.

Nothing, actually. The posted code has undefined behavior caused by access out of bounds of `triplets` and the wrong format specifier for `limit`.

```
unsigned int limit;
scanf("%d", &limit);
//     ^^  It should be %u

unsigned int triples[limit][3]; // `0.969 * limit` is exact
//                   ^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Nope.
```

`limit` is used to bound the value of the bigger cathetus, but it's not enough as count of the number of triplets.

We can write a more simple (IMHO) version of the brute force algorithm, without using any floating-point function from `<math.h>`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long sq(unsigned long long x)
{
    return x * x;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int limit;

    printf("Max value to bruteforce: ");
    scanf("%u", &limit);    // input validation is left to the reader.

    puts("\nBruteforcing...");
    unsigned count = 0;

    // The produced triplets will be ordered by the hypotenuse
    // and then the catheti.
    for(unsigned int c = 5; c < limit; ++c)
    {
        for(unsigned int a = 3, b = c - 1; a < b; --b)
        { //                    ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^  ^^^
          // The catheti must be greater than 0,
          // different from the hypotenuse and
          // from each other (sqrt(2) is irrational, so...).
            unsigned long long dif = sq(c) - sq(b);
            while ( sq(a) < dif )
            {
                ++a;
            }
            if ( sq(a) == dif )
            {
                ++count;
                printf("%4u %4u %4u\n", a, b, c);
                ++a;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%u triplets found.\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Live: https://godbolt.org/z/hvTa9zKW4

Comment: Thanks, was just about to answer my own post using a similar method that worked out. I'll try this though.